# Is there a way to hide empty sourceSets in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, source-sets

I'm writing a Kotlin Multiplatform project in Android Studio. As a result, I have multiple sourceSets configured in the project but some of them are empty. Removing them from the Gradle build is not possible as they are required for building the project. Is there a way to hide them from being displayed by the IDE?

(Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**There is no built-in way to hide empty source sets, but you can create a custom annotation to do this.**

Here is the Example. I Hope It would help you.

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class HideEmptySourceSet
```

For more details about annotations check this link:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to annotate with it? There are no classes in the empty source sets and I'm not aware of any way to create annotations for gradle items.

Answer (score 0):

Click the dropdown at the top labeled "Android" and select the "Project" view instead. This will display only the directories that are actually present on the filesystem rather than showing every source set that's configured.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution comes with a lot more changes than I'm looking for. I find the Android view more convenient and better organized than the Project view.

Comment: In that case I don't have any other suggestions, sorry. I find the Android view more confusing because it hides things and doesn't reflect the actual state of the files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such option built-in in Android Studio environment.

It's also possible to use a different view (e.g. Project) or define **bookmarks** and **favourites** to navigate around quickly.

I would advise to try out the favourites, as setting up will take about 3 minutes and will make it way more comfortable to use.